# If $f(x)$ is a polynomial satisfying $ f(x)f(\frac 1x) = f(x)+f(\frac 1x)$ and $f(3)=28$, then how could we find $f(4)$?

Tags: polynomials, algebra-precalculus

> If $f(x)$ is a polynomial satisfying $  f(x)f(\frac 1x) = f(x)+f(\frac
>  1x)$ and $f(3)=28$, then how could we find $f(4)$ ?

Comment: How about re-writing it as $$\big(f(x)-1\big)\cdot\big(f(1/x)-1\big)=1$$

Comment: @GEdgar:and then ...?

Comment: ... and then we know $f(x)-1 = x^m$ for some $m$ or $f(x)-1 = -x^m$ for some $m$ as the only ways to get it.  Assuming INTEGER COEFFICIENTS (which is not stated), from $\pm 3^m = 27$ we have a good guess for $m$ and the sign.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solving the functional equation for $f\left(\frac{1}{x} \right) = \frac{f(x)}{f(x)-1}$. This means that $f(x)-1$ must be a monomial. Let $f(x) = 1 + c x^d$. Then 
$$
   c \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)^d +1 = \frac{1}{c} \left( \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)^d + c \right)
$$
This, implies $c^2 = 1$. Now use $f(3) = 28$ to determined $c$ and $d$. Since $28 = 1 + 1 \times 3^3$, we conclude $c=1$ and $d=3$.

Thus $f(4) = 1 + 4^3 = 65$.

Comment: I never studied functional equations before, is it algebra pre-calculus?

Comment: Never mind, replace the phrase functional equation with equation. As a side note, the problem asks you to solve the functional equation (i.e. equation for a function, satisfied for every $x$) in polynomials. You may glance though [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_equation) page on functional equations. Another famous functional equation is $f(x+1) = 2 f(x)$, which is solved by $f(x) = f_0 2^x$.

Comment: Two things (1)why $f(x)-1$ must be a monomial ? (2) what is $f_0$ in your comment? is it f(0)?

Comment: @MaX Rational function $f(x)/(f(x)-1)$ is a polynomial in $\frac{1}{x}$. Set $d$ be a degree of this polynomial. This $x^d f\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $d$, denote it $p(x)$. Thus, $x^d f(x) = (f(x)-1) p(x)$, and $(-x^d + p(x)) f(x) = p(x)$. Since $f(x)$ has degree $d$ and $p(x)$ has degree $d$, it follows that $p(x)-x^d$ is a constant, thus $p(x) = c + x^d$ and $f(x) = p\left(\frac{1}{x} \right) x^d = c x^d + 1$.

Comment: @MaX Yes, $f_0$ is an arbitrary constant, and $f(0) = f_0$. I think GEdgar's hint is the most elegant way to arrive at $f(x) = 1 + c x^d$, with $c^2 = 1$.

Comment: I am lost, I don't know why can't I understand!!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1839/discussion-between-sasha-and-max)