# How to find $f(x)$, if $f(x)+f(1/x)=f(x)f(1/x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

So this is actually a part of another question:

> If a polynomial $f$ satisfies: $$\log_2[f(x)]=\log_2\left[2+\frac 23+\frac 29+\cdots +\infty\right]\cdot \log_3 \left[1+ \frac{f(x)}{f(1/x)} \right] $$
> if $f(10)=1001,$ find $f(20)$

So, I actually thought, to find $f(x)$ polynomial altogether, since I couldn't get any another clue. simplifiying that long equation yields us this equation :
$$f(x)+f(1/x)=f(x)f(1/x)$$, after which i am stuck and unable to proceed further. Putting different values of $x$ won't benefit, as far I tried. Any help is massively appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't remember the derivation at the moment, but the answer to such functional equation is $f(x)=1±x^n$, which in this case should be $f(x)=1+x^3$. This *might* help, I guess.

Comment: @ultralegend5385, Thank you for the answer, but I came here specificly for the derived answer. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the series of fractions? We have $2+2/3+2/9+\cdots$, a decreasing sequence, but it ends in $\infty$... What's the pattern?

Comment: @FShrike Its an infinite GP with common ratio $1/3$

Comment: A very simple solution to the functional equation is $f(x) = 1+x$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$f(x)f(1/x)=f(x)+f(1/x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254586/fxf1-x-fxf1-x) See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3760171) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/794944). All found via [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/).

Comment: [Actually](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3385631), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3405839) [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2731866/) [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1098449) [really](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/472708) [very](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3594223) [very](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84604) [often](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3144979).